# Why this error? Missing $ inserted

Tags: tables, errors, compiling

I've not opened any $.. and i'm not using any mathematical command (apart \pm but this is not the problem because it doesn't work the same). The first error is just after the first \end{tabular}. I created a table and subtable environement, maybe I can't manage them well, please help me.

```
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
    \subtable{
      \begin{tabular}{ll}

    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Molla 1}}\\
    \hline
    $R_s$ &      1.48\pm0.01 cm\\
    $n_s$   & 41 \pm1\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$l_0=23.2 \pm 0.2$cm}\\
    \hline
    massa (g) & $\delta{l}$ (cm)\\
    \hline
    38.8\pm0.1      & 9\pm0.5\\
    148.1\pm0.2     & 13.5\pm0.5\\
    235.6\pm0.3     & 21.2\pm0.5\\
    336.6\pm0.4     & 30.3\pm0.5\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \qquad
\subtable{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Molla 2}}\\
    \hline
    $R_s$   &    0.93   \pm0.01 cm\\
    $n_s$   & 66 \pm1\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{$l_0=19.1 \pm 0.2$cm}\\
    \hline
    massa (g) & $\delta{l}$ (cm)\\
    \hline
    87.5\pm0.1      & 3\pm0.5\\
    188.5\pm0.2     & 6.5\pm0.5\\
    237.5\pm0.3     & 8.2\pm0.5\\
    336.6\pm0.4     & 11.8\pm0.5\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    }
    \end{table}
    \clearpage
```

Comment: `\pm` is a mathematical symbol which can't be used in text-mode. You need to enclose all the math stuff in dollars, like `$87.5\pm0.1$`. Yes, it's a bit heavy notation, but that's it (there're some ways how to avoid this, but I'm not so sure that they are really simpler). Yeah, and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried to do that but it doesn't go! I can compile using TeXniccenter but it also reports errors. Neither array environment works. always the same error

Comment: Then please post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), inluding the relevant packages, the document class etc. Without that, it is impossible for us to resolve your problem.